# Does ELU want a tag called "ELL"

Tags: discussion

I've just rejected an edit [for a tag called "ELL"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/105).

It doesn't seem right to me that ELU should have or use such a tag, but what do others think?

Comment: I agree. If you don't want it here, ship it off, but a tag's not going to help. Link to some of those superior answers on ELL if you want people to choose it.

Comment: @John: Well, the tag is for [ELU.meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ell), not the main site (perhaps I should have made that clear). But I assume if there's a question/invitation to discussion here on ELU meta that someone thinks should be tagged ELL, the post should have been made on ELL.meta in the first place. I just feel it's not really up to ELU to discuss (define?) the scope of ELL *here*, while that site is still in beta.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh! I didn’t realize you meant it as a tag for here on meta!

Comment: @tchrist: I personally didn't "mean" the tag as anything. I just accepted the system's prompt to review a description someone had added (to a tag that presumably already existed here). I didn't realise immediately that *meta* tags are completely separate from *main* tags, so I started of with knee-jerk antipathy myself. But even when I grasped that distinction, I still thought the implication that folks on ELU might discuss (and thereby perhaps *define*) ELL was somehow a bit like "talking behind their back". As I'm in both sites, I might get seriously confused.

Comment: ...actually, I see that RegDwight has since overruled my rejection and *approved* the description. I'm not looking to start an argument with mods, but I stand by my question.

Comment: No big thing. Have it or not. I don't particularly see the use, but I don't think it gets in the way.

Comment: @Mitch: Well, I both sites will use their own *meta* to debate what is and isn't On Topic, but I'm not convinced ELU.meta should be encouraging statements along the lines of *this doesn't belong on ELU, it should be on ELL*.

Comment: Oh, as to debate, really, what's wrong with debates about whether something belongs on ELL vs ELU? (Note we're having a debate about having debates. just felt the need to point that out. Also, I feel the need to point out that I'm pointing that out, even though it's obvious. Why it's obvious...let me think...yes, that's obvious too))

Comment: @Mitch: Well, I think [questions like this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121334/), for example, shouldn't be on ELU. The fact that I think such a question *should* be on ***ELL*** isn't really relevant, if I'm making that point on ELU.meta. I vaguely feel that discussion about what should or shouldn't be on ELL ought to take place on ***ELL.meta***, not here. Since ELU is a much bigger and longer established site, I think it should maintain a "distance" from ELL, to give the new site a proper chance to establish its own identity and scope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are legitimate questions on ELU meta about ELL. I suspect there's a lot of them.

Tagging those questions as being about ELL seems logical. It means that people won't ask questions on meta that have already been answered.

If someone were to tag an ELU main question as [belongs-on-ell](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-ell), that'd be a different matter.

Comment: Okay, I'll go for that. Your final point is the clincher for me. I've only just looked at the two ELU.meta questions tagged ***ELL***, and neither of them contain any direct references to what type of questions *should* be on ELL, so I guess I overreacted to a "non-issue".